# how to use a plugin inside a groovy plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am trying to migrate tasks from build.gradle to a plugin that do it.
In my build.gradle I do this:

```
plugins {
    //id 'java'
    id 'war'

    //https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.gretty
    id 'org.gretty' version '3.0.1'

    id "com.github.dkorotych.gradle-maven-exec" version "2.2.1"

}
apply plugin: 'maven'

....
....

prepareFrontEnd (type: MavenExec, dependsOn: build) {
    goals 'vaadin:prepare-frontend'
}


task buildFrontEnd (type: MavenExec, dependsOn: prepareFrontEnd) {
    goals 'vaadin:build-frontend'
}
```

Now I am moving this stuff to a plugins:

```
package com.github.mdre.hgvaadinplugin

import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
//import com.github.dkorotych.gradle.maven.exec.MavenExec;


class HGVaadinPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        println "Hybrid Gradle Vaaadin plugin."
        project.plugins.apply('com.github.dkorotych.gradle-maven-exec')
        // project.getPluginManager().apply('gradle-maven-exec-plugin')

        project.task('prepareFrontEnd', type: MavenExec){
            dependsOn build
            doLast {
                goal 'vaadin:prepare-frontend'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to import the class MavenExec I get this error:

```
> Task :compileGroovy FAILED
startup failed:
/home/mdre/Proyectos/HGVaadinPlugin/src/main/groovy/com/github/mdre/hgvaadinplugin/HGVaadinPlugin.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class com.github.dkorotych.gradle.maven.exec.MavenExec
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import com.github.dkorotych.gradle.maven.exec.MavenExec;
   ^
```

and if I comment the import line, I get this error in the project that use the plugin:

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'VaadinFlowLab'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.github.mdre.hgvaadinplugin']
  >   No such property: MavenExec for class: com.github.mdre.hgvaadinplugin.HGVaadinPlugin

How could I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want `gradle-maven-exec` as a dependency (or a buildSrc dependency if you're writing the plugin inline in a project)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fix it!

I forget to include the dependency class in the final jar. So all of I need was to add this to the build.config:

```
configurations {
    // configuration that holds jars to include in the jar
    extraLibs
}

dependencies {
    ....
    ....
    //necesario para crear un fatJar
    extraLibs "gradle.plugin.com.github.dkorotych.gradle.maven.exec:gradle-maven-exec-plugin:2.2.1"
    configurations.compile.extendsFrom(configurations.extraLibs)
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.extraLibs.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

and now it is working!!